# Error: module java.base does not "opens java.util"

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am migrating an application from Java 11 to Java 17, when running some tests I am facing the following issue:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.lang.Object[] java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.a accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @1fb19a0
            at com.twitter.chill.java.ArraysAsListSerializer.<init>(ArraysAsListSerializer.java:69)
            at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.FlinkChillPackageRegistrar.registerSerializers(FlinkChillPackageRegistrar.java:67)
            at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.getKryoInstance(KryoSerializer.java:512)
            at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.checkKryoInitialized(KryoSerializer.java:521)
            at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.copy(KryoSerializer.java:306)`
```

I found in the Apache Flink [documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/java_compatibility/) the following: "JDK classes/internal must be explicitly allowed by the application when it is started, on a per-module basis, in the form of `-–add-opens/-–add-exports` JVM arguments."

I tried to run the tests using the JVM argument:
`--add-opens java.lang/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED`

But I still getting the same issue.

Does anyone knows what should I do?

Comment: Can you try `--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED` because `java.util` is in the module `java.base`?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue: As I am using gradle and it creates a separated process to perform the tests, the jvm arguments were not properly passed to the tests.

I modified the gradle scripts to something like this:

> ```
> test { 
>    jvmArgs = listOf("--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED")
> }
> ```

Then the tests were correctly executed with no issues.

Comment: Could you link to some documentation?

Comment: Here it is the documentation: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/deployment/java_compatibility/#jdk-modularization